# Linphone core listener not receiving incoming calls

Tags: android, voip, sip-server

I was trying to add sip incoming calls  with linphone sdk, The registration is successful and I can make out going calls and the call status is logging as expected, but I am not able to receive incoming calls. I am using intent service to handle connection.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String sipAddress = intent.getStringExtra("address");
        String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        final LinphoneCoreFactory lcFactory = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance();

        // First instantiate the core Linphone object given only a listener.
        // The listener will react to events in Linphone core.
        try {
            lc = lcFactory.createLinphoneCore(new LinphoneCoreListenerBase() {
                @Override
                public void callState(LinphoneCore lc, LinphoneCall call, LinphoneCall.State state, String message) {
                    super.callState(lc, call, state, message);
                    Log.i(TAG, "callState: ");
                }
            }, getApplication());
        } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lc.setUserAgent("Test app", "1.0");

        try {
            LinphoneAddress address = lcFactory.createLinphoneAddress(sipAddress);
            String username = address.getUserName();
            String domain = address.getDomain();
            if (password != null) {
                lc.addAuthInfo(lcFactory.createAuthInfo(username, password, null, domain));
            }
            // create proxy config
            LinphoneProxyConfig proxyCfg = lc.createProxyConfig(sipAddress, domain, null, true);
            proxyCfg.setExpires(2000);
            lc.addProxyConfig(proxyCfg); // add it to linphone
            lc.setDefaultProxyConfig(proxyCfg);


            running = true;
            while (running) {
                lc.iterate(); // first iterate initiates registration
                sleep(20);
            }
        } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: (Pro-tip: we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.)

Answer (score 0):

As the IntentService document (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) stated:

> the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

I think you should not put the listener in an IntentService. Instead, put it in a long running Service so that the listener can actually keep staying there to receive events.