# Linphone sdk based Sip App force stops while receiving Incoming Calls with a fatal exception

Tags: android, android-studio, sip, linphone-sdk

I am developing a sip application that do sip to sip and sip to other phone calls. I also wanted to record the both. Finally, I found out that the linphone-sdk can solve the problems. I had integrated Linphone-sdk from their maven repository to my app. I am using another Sip client for calls (Not a linphone account). Outgoing calls are working perfectly. But, whenever we receive an incoming call to the sip account, the app gets terminated with an error in log cat.

As answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023975/linphone-core-listener-not-receiving-incoming-calls),
I changed the corresponding linphone service to a long running service, which can receive incoming calls when the app is not in the foreground. But that doesn't solve the problem.

```
mHandler = new Handler();
        // This will be our main Core listener, it will change activities depending on events
        mCoreListener = new CoreListenerStub() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(Core core, Call call, Call.State state, String message) {
                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "onCallStateChanged: ");

                if (state == Call.State.IncomingReceived || state == Call.State.IncomingEarlyMedia) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onCallReceived: ");
                    // For this sample we will automatically answer incoming calls
                    CallParams params = getCore().createCallParams(call);
                    params.enableVideo(false);
                    call.acceptWithParams(params);
               .....
            }
        };
```

As per the code, the call will be answered automatically, But for incoming calls, onCallStateChanged()never gets called and the logical output is as follows :

...
...

```
    2019-07-23 14:56:50.468 9248-9248/com.call.mysipapp I/liblinphone: Found payload AMR/8000 fmtp=mode-change-period=2
    2019-07-23 14:56:50.469 9248-9248/com.call.mysipapp I/liblinphone: Found payload AMR/8000 fmtp=mode-change-period=1

    --------- beginning of crash
2019-07-23 14:56:50.473 9248-9248/com.call.mysipapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x28 in tid 9248 (m.call.mysipapp)
```

Comment: Try disabling instant run and see if it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0

Comment: Also, it seems the error is in native code, you might want to google how to trace NDK errors to find out exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Instant run is disabled in my case. I gone through this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked

But don't found out what I want. Also the linphone application itself is still having a bug like this.